# How can I check model's attribute in router in backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

Okay. I want model's "loggedIn" attribute in router's home action to check whether user is logged in or not. Here is my code. **Please check router's home action.**

```
LoginStatus Model
--------------------
window.LoginStatus = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        loggedIn: false,
        userId: null,
        email: null,
        error: "Error!"
    },

    initialize: function() {
        //_bindAll(this, 'getSession', 'setStorage');
    },

    getSession: function(email, password) {
        var self = this;
        var url = '../api/login';
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:"json",
            data: {
                email: email,
                password: password
            },
            success:function (data) {
                //console.log(["Login request details: ", data]);               
                if(data.error) {  // If there is an error, show the error messages
                    $('.alert-error').text(data.error.text).show();
                }
                else { // If not, send them back to the home page
                    self.setStorage(data.id, data.email);
                    Backbone.history.navigate("#dashboard", {trigger : true});
                }
            }
        });
    },

    setStorage: function(userId, email) {
        //alert(userId);

        localStorage.setItem("userId", userId);
        localStorage.setItem("email", email);
        this.set({ "loggedIn" : true});
    }
});

Backbone Router
---------------
window.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "login": "login",
        "dashboard": "dashboard",
    },

    initialize: function() {

    },

    home: function() {
        /*Here I want to check whether user is logged in or not something like  
            if (loginStatus.loggedIn)
                render dashbord template
            else 
                render login template

            HOW CAN I WRITE ABOVE THING/LOGIC ? */

    },

    login: function() {
        $('#container').html(new LoginView().render().el);
    },

    dashboard: function() {     
        $('#container').html(new DashboardView().render().el);
        $('#dynamic_css').attr('href','css/dashboard.css');
    }

});
```

Thanks, Jimit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it on initialize an then use it everywhere.

```
initialize: function() {
    this.loginStatus = new LoginStatus();
},

home: function() {
    if (this.loginStatus.get('loggedIn')  
        // render dashbord template
    else 
        // render login template
},
```